# How to perform a two-tailed 2-sample t-test in R

Tags: r, t-test

I've following problem creating a two-tailed 2-sample t-test. The only values given are the values below. We have two groups S and L, which have mid-term and final exams. My task is to perform  a two-tailed 2-sample t-test once on the mid-semester scores and then on the difference of scores from mid-semester to end-semester examinations.

```
d <- read.table(text="
Cohort  N Midterm_Mean Midterm_SD Final_Mean Final_SD Diff_Mean Diff_SD
2016_L 38     77.4        3.0       73.7       4.2      -3.7        2.1
2017_S 37     81.9        2.1       70.0       4.6     -11.9        2.8
", header=TRUE)
```

The results should be:

- for the midterms: (t: -1.24, p:0.219 > 0.01, Cohen's d: -0.286)
- for the finals:  (t:2.30, p:0.024 > 0.01, Cohen's d:0.532)

I don't get those results. How can i realize the test properly in R ?

EDIT: I already have following:

```
L1 <- rnorm(mean = 77.4, sd = 3,   n=38)
S1 <- rnorm(mean = 81.9, sd = 2.1, n=37)
L2 <- rnorm(mean = 73.7, sd = 4.2, n=38)
S2 <- rnorm(mean = 70,   sd = 4.6, n=37)
tab <- data.frame(result=c(L1,S1), 
                  group=c(rep(0, times=38), rep(1,times =37)) ,head=TRUE)
attach(tab)
t <- t.test (result ~ group, mu=0, alternative="two.sided", 
             conf=0.95, var.equal=T, paired=F)
```

The code above is just for comparing the mid terms. First of all, I thought that I had to create normal vectors with given values. Than I put them into a data frame together and mark them with 0 or 1 whether they are from (S) or (L). Is that more or less the right way to solve the task? Because the result gets a too small p-value.

Comment: what should the first one bea t-value of -1124 or a p-value or 0.219? Neither seem reasonable given how you framed the question with the data

Comment: Hi @mojo, and welcome to StackOverfow. I've gone ahead and added the information from your other post and flagged it for deletion, or if that doesn't happen before you see this, go ahead and delete that post yourself. The way StackOverflow works is different from a usual message board; instead of adding new posts, the idea is that you edit your original question to make it as clear as possible

Comment: @Robin: t-value should be 1.24. But....

Comment: @mojo: The results you posted are incorrect, the correct p-values are much smaller. Are you sure you copied them right?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're not really on the right track at all. I assume this is for a homework assignment? In real life, you almost always start with the raw data, that's what R expects. But here you don't have the raw data, you only have the summary statistics. So you need to do the computations yourself to get the answer. (In your edit, you're making up new raw data that looks kind of like the real data -- but not exactly, of course.)

Since this feels like homework, I won't provide those computations here; instead, look in your text for the formulas and follow them. The basic idea is to get a difference, divide by a standard error (which you'll need to compute from these two standard deviations and sample size), and then use a normal table (or an R function) to get the p-value. Try that out and then come back with any followup questions -- by editing the original question.

Comment: okay thank you first of all. I do have a presentation about Parrondo's Paradoxon and that was the part how students of a basic lecture and students of lecture with integrated Paradoxon simulation perform in their tests about that topic. The thing is that in the text, the only provided information about the students success is the table above with the above mentioned results of the t-test. That is the reason why i've tried to do the t-test on my own to reconstruct the mentioned results.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional information. This is a better question for the statistics site, then as it's not really about the coding, but about what to do. There are already a couple questions there that address this; see for example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30394/3601. After you see what's there, here are some potential options: 1) if they answer your question, come back and delete this one,  2) if you still don't understand what to do, ask a question about the statistics there (and delete this one), or 3) if you understand what to do but not how to do it in R, update this one.

Comment: The Wikipedia page also has a lot of good background information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test

Answer (score 0):

Check ?t.test

You'll see you need to hand it two vectors (x and y). The default is to test mean difference of zero. Two-sided tests are also the default. You might toggle whether equivalent variance is assumed -- var.equal = TRUE.

The way you're reporting your p-values is non-standard. I don't quite see what the result is supposed to be.